# onsubmit still submits form even on return false from ajax verification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am verifying my form using ajax, im just checking if there is a duplicate username, if there is it will return false, else return true.

here is my ajax:

```
function checkform(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Delivery/usernamecheck/", 
        data: {username: username},
        type:'post',
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data > 0){
                $("#info").attr("class","form-group has-error");
                $("#info1").html("Duplicate Username!");
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my html:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Delivery/reg/" method = "post" onsubmit=" return checkform();">
</form>
```

even on return false the form still submits. any idea why?

also there are no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent submitting of the form by returning false in ajax response it need to be in that function, solution is to always return false and resubmit in ajax response:

```
var secondCall = false;
function checkform(){
    if (secondCall) {
        return;
    }
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Delivery/usernamecheck/", 
        data: {username: username},
        type:'post',
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data > 0){
                $("#info").attr("class","form-group has-error");
                $("#info1").html("Duplicate Username!");
            }else{
                secondCall = true;
                $('.form-signin').submit();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Note that it's better to bind submit event in JavaScript:

```
$('.form-signin').submit(checkform);
```

Comment: $('.form-signin').submit(checkform); <- what do you mean by this? thank you for your answer, i will give it a try

Comment: @magicianIam it's the same as onsubmit in html but added in javascript.

Comment: i tried and got this error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: @magicianIam It probably keep calling that function and never realy submit the form, I've try to fix that and edit the answer.

Comment: it worked, thanks!. so what it was doing before was like a loop, and to break that loop you introduced some flags, though why does that happen anyway? so that i might avoid that in the future. thanks again :)

Comment: @magicianIam it was like recursion because `.submit()` was executing that function again.